# Calculating curvature from a set of normal vectors along a wave

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a set of normal vectors along a curve and want to calculate the curvature at each point.  I'm not sure how to do this.  Thank you in advance for your help :)

[image]

Comment: Hi ForeverHopeful and welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) accordingly. Please explain better what is that you have. Numeric or analytic?  Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If  you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) it will inspire great answers.

Comment: You could use the formula $|\kappa| = \|d{\bf n}/ds\|$.  Some code/data to play with would make it easier for folks to show you how to code it.

Answer (score 4):

Aw heck, here's a first-order forward difference approximation to the derivative, with unit normal vectors generated from a sine graph.  The curvature `kappa` is shown in gold.

```
data = Table[{{x, Sin[x]}, Normalize@Cross@{1, Cos[x]}}, {x, 0., 6., 0.1}];

kappa = Ratios /@ 
    MapAt[Norm, Differences@MapAt[Apply[ArcTan], data, {All, 2}], {All, 1}] // 
   Flatten;
Graphics[{
  Thick,
  {ColorData[97][1], Line[data[[All, 1]]]},
  Arrow[{#, # + #2}] & @@@ data,
  {ColorData[97][2], Line@Transpose@{MovingAverage[data[[All, 1, 1]], 2], kappa}}
  }, Frame -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And here's a second-order central difference approximation to the derivative, which doesn't look a lot different from the above graphics:

```
kappa = Ratios /@ 
    MapAt[Norm, 
     Differences[MapAt[Apply[ArcTan], data, {All, 2}], 1, 2], {All, 1}] //
   Flatten;
Graphics[{
  Thick,
  {ColorData[97][1], Line[data[[All, 1]]]},
  Arrow[{#, # + #2}] & @@@ data,
  {ColorData[97][2], Line@Transpose@{data[[2 ;; -2, 1, 1]], kappa}}
  }, Frame -> True, Axes -> True]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `FrenetSerretSystem` combined with `Interpolation` (using only the first parts of the input data  and ignoring the part corresponding to the normals) as follows:

```
ClearAll[curvature, f, if]
curvature[f_, t_] := First@First@FrenetSerretSystem[{t, f[t]}, t]
```

Using `data` with a structure similar to the one in Michael E2's answer:

```
f = Sin;
data = Table[{{x, f[x]}, Normalize@Cross@{1, f'[x]}}, {x, 0., 6., 0.1}];
arrows = Graphics[{Red, Arrowheads[.025], Arrow[{#, # + #2}] & @@@ data}]; 

if = Interpolation[data[[All, 1]]];
Show[ParametricPlot[Evaluate @ {{t, if[t]}, {t, curvature[if, t] }}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
  arrows, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Using `f = # Sin[Cos@#]&`, we get

[image]